# How to marshal JSON with repeating groups in a fixed length data format in java using camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, marshalling

I need to process a JSON - it has repeating groups
I need to convert it to fixed length record

```
{
    "blockType" : "BL-H ",
    "blockTypeLength" : "00000031",
    "blockId" : "S62951156229900",
    "totalNoOfTX" : "001",
    "msgblockType" : "TX-S ",
    "messageLength" : "00000728",
    "noa":[
        {
            "title":"Behin",
            "artist":"LIMP ",
            "itunes_link":"http:behind"
        },
        {
            "title":"Alone",
            "artist":"ALYSS",
            "itunes_link":"http:clk.doubler.com"
        }
    ]

}
```

Should be converted to BehinLIMP http:behindAloneALYSShttp:clk.doubler.com

I can have one to many such groups in the request

What I have tried -

```
DataFormat bindy = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(myModel.class);

                from("direct:testUnmarshall")
            .log("${body}")
            //.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, BillingBookingRequest[].class)
            .inputType(BillingBookingRequest.class)
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    try {
                        BillingBookingRequest responseBody = exchange.getMessage().getBody(BillingBookingRequest.class);

                        ZvkkRequest requestBody = new ZvkkRequest();
                        requestBody.setBlockType(responseBody.getBlockType());
                        requestBody.setBlockTypeLength(responseBody.getBlockTypeLength());
                        requestBody.setBlockId(responseBody.getBlockId());
                        requestBody.setTotalNoOfTX(responseBody.getTotalNoOfTX());
                        requestBody.setMsgblockType(responseBody.getMsgblockType());
                        requestBody.setMessageLength(responseBody.getMessageLength());

                        List<DAO> noaList = responseBody.getNoa();
                        List<DAOFix> repGrp = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DAO noa:
                             noaList) {
                            DAOFix obj = new DAOFix();
                            obj.setArtist(noa.getArtist());obj.setTitle(noa.getTitle());obj.setItunes_link(noa.getItunes_link());
                            repGrp.add(obj);
                        }

                        requestBody.setRepeatingGrp(repGrp);
                        exchange.getOut().setBody(requestBody);
                    } catch (Exception exception){
                        System.out.println("EXCEPTION HERE :: "+exception.getMessage());
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            })
            .log("Before marshal ....... ${body}")
            .marshal(bindy)
            .log("After marshal ....... ${body}")
            .to("{{file.path}}fileName=check.dat")
            .end();
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
also observed - org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: myFixedLengthRequestModel to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value myFixedLengthRequestModel[with all the values]
```

I have used the corresponding models holding the values for json as well as @FixedLengthRecord
need help to understand and get this resolved.

```
public class ZvkkRequest {
@DataField(pos = 1, length=5, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
private String blockType;
@DataField(pos = 2, length=8, align = "R", paddingChar='0')
private int blockTypeLength;
@DataField(pos = 3, length=15, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
private String blockId;
@DataField(pos = 4, length=3, align = "R", paddingChar='0')
private int totalNoOfTX;
@DataField(pos = 5, length=5, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
private String msgblockType;
@DataField(pos = 6, length=8, align = "R", paddingChar='0')
private int messageLength;

@OneToMany(mappedTo = "classpath.DAOFix")
private List<DAOFix> repeatingGrp;
}

class DAOFix {

@DataField(pos = 7, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
private String title;
@DataField(pos = 8, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
private String artist;
@DataField(pos = 9, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
private String itunes_link;
```

}

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple repeating fields in fixedLengthformat ?

Comment: I don't see you unmarshal the json to pojo at any point are you doing that in some other route? Seeing the bindy annotated(?) `myFixedLengthRequestModel` class could also help solve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Pasi Österman
  @DataField(pos = 6, length=8, align = "R", paddingChar='0')
    private int messageLength;
    @OneToMany(mappedTo = "com.db.gtbb.adapter.zvkk.model.Noa")
    @DataField(pos = 7, length=5, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
    private List<Noa> noaLength;

Comment: Hi @Pasi Österman - i have tried below two ways - 
1.  Here after adding @OneToMany tag i am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

`@DataField(pos = 6, length=8, align = "R", paddingChar='0')
    private int messageLength;
    @OneToMany(mappedTo = "com.model.Noa")
    @DataField(pos = 7, length=5, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
    private List<Noa> noaLength;`

Comment: 2.  With this approach i can get the data converted to fixed length but i can only store one object
`@DataField(pos = 7, length=5, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
    private String title;
    @DataField(pos = 8, length=5, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
    private String artist;
    @DataField(pos = 9, length=20, align = "L", paddingChar=' ')
    private String itunes_link;`

Comment: Is it mandatory to unmarshal the json i am able to get the values though in my processor?

Comment: It's generally recommended that one modifies the question to add in additional details than using comment section since it supports better formatting, doesn't have the constraints of a comment and is easier to read.

Comment: It's not mandatory to unmarshal json, if you just want values from specific field(s) you can use jsonpath library or use custom processor or lamda that fetches the value(s) you need using something like `ObjectMapper` and `JsonNode` from jackson library. But often its just easier (and more future proof) to just unmarshal the json to pojo(s) and get the values you need to create objects you can marshal to csv.

Comment: I am getting After marshal ....... BL-H 00000031S62951156229900001TX-S 00000728
The list objects are not getting added to the fixed length record after marshalling @PasiÖsterman Can you please suggest ? awaiting for your response

Comment: I would like to know, what the use of this is. Why converting structured data into a string line? I can see your problem, but don't understand the reason behind. Can you help me with a short explanation?

Comment: I mean how do you unmarshall this?

Comment: Hi @JanosVinceller - requirement for me is to convert this json request to a fixed length format - as the backend only understand it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this out and it seems `@OneToMany` does not seem to work with `BindyFixedLengthDataFormat` like it does with `BindyCsvDataFormat` this means that you'll likely process the json and create multiple object instances which you can then marshal in to fixed length record with Bindy.

Below is code I used to test this out as well as one way (`direct:bindyFixedLenghtProcessed`) to convert single `ZvkkRequest` instance to list of `ZvkkRequestFixedLenght` instances which you can then marshal to `BindyFixedLengthDataFormat`

```java
public class ExampleTests extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Test
    public void bindyCSVTest(){

        // Test bindy @OneToMany with BindyCsvDataFormat 
        template.sendBody("direct:bindyCSV", testJson);
    }

    @Test
    public void bindyFixedLenghtTest(){

        // Test bindy @OneToMany with BindyFixedLengthDataFormat
        template.sendBody("direct:bindyFixedLenght", testJson);
    }

    @Test
    public void bindyFixedLenghtProcessedTest(){

        // Test workaraound 
        template.sendBody("direct:bindyFixedLenghtProcessed", testJson);
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        
        return new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                
                // Doesn't seem to work with OneToMany
                DataFormat bindyCSV = new BindyCsvDataFormat(ZvkkRequest.class);

                from("direct:bindyCSV")
                    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ZvkkRequest.class)
                    .marshal(bindyCSV)
                    .log("${body}");

                DataFormat bindyFixedLenght = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(ZvkkRequest.class);

                from("direct:bindyFixedLenght")
                    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ZvkkRequest.class)
                    .marshal(bindyFixedLenght)
                    .log("${body}");

                DataFormat bindyFixedLenght2 = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(ZvkkRequestFixedLenght.class);

                from("direct:bindyFixedLenghtProcessed")
                    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ZvkkRequest.class)
                    .process(new Processor(){

                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            
                            ZvkkRequest body = exchange.getMessage()
                                .getBody(ZvkkRequest.class);
                            
                            List<ZvkkRequestFixedLenght> requests = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (DAOFix it : body.noa) {
                                ZvkkRequestFixedLenght request = new ZvkkRequestFixedLenght();
                                request.blockType = body.blockType;
                                request.blockTypeLength = body.blockTypeLength;
                                request.blockId = body.blockId;
                                request.totalNoOfTX = body.totalNoOfTX;
                                request.msgblockType = body.msgblockType;
                                request.messageLength = body.messageLength;
                                request.artist = it.artist;
                                request.title = it.title;
                                request.itunesLink = it.itunesLink;
                                requests.add(request);
                            }
                            exchange.getMessage().setBody(requests);
                        }
                        
                    })
                    .marshal(bindyFixedLenght2)
                    .log("${body}");

            }
        };
    }

    String testJson = "{" +
    "    \"blockType\" : \"BL-H \"," +
    "    \"blockTypeLength\" : \"00000031\"," +
    "    \"blockId\" : \"S62951156229900\"," +
    "    \"totalNoOfTX\" : \"001\"," +
    "    \"msgblockType\" : \"TX-S \"," +
    "    \"messageLength\" : \"00000728\"," +
    "    \"noa\":[" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"title\":\"Behin\"," +
    "            \"artist\":\"LIMP \"," +
    "            \"itunes_link\":\"http:behind\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"title\":\"Alone\"," +
    "            \"artist\":\"ALYSS\"," +
    "            \"itunes_link\":\"http:clk.doubler.com\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}";
}
```

bindyFixedLenghtProcessedTest logs following:

```sh
BL-H 00000031S62951156229900001TX-S 00000728BehinLIMP                    http:behind
BL-H 00000031S62951156229900001TX-S 00000728AloneALYSS          http:clk.doubler.com
```

In case you want to have these on a **single line** you can try to marshal `ZvkkRequest` and `DAOFix` separately and use **string concatenation** to combine the unmarshalled `DAOFix` entries to unmarshalled `ZvkkRequest`.

**ZvkkRequest.java**

```java
@FixedLengthRecord
@CsvRecord(separator=",")
public class ZvkkRequest {
    
    @DataField(pos = 1, length = 5, align = "L", paddingChar = ' ')
    public String blockType;

    @DataField(pos = 2, length = 8, align = "R", paddingChar = '0')
    public int blockTypeLength;
    
    @DataField(pos = 3, length = 15, align = "L", paddingChar = ' ')
    public String blockId;
    
    @DataField(pos = 4, length = 3, align = "R", paddingChar = '0')
    public int totalNoOfTX;
    
    @DataField(pos = 5, length = 5, align = "L", paddingChar = ' ')
    public String msgblockType;
    
    @DataField(pos = 6, length = 8, align = "R", paddingChar = '0')
    public int messageLength;

    @OneToMany
    public List<DAOFix> noa;
}
```

**DAOFix.java**

```java
public class DAOFix {

    @DataField(pos = 7, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
    public String title;
    
    @DataField(pos = 8, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
    public String artist;

    @JsonProperty("itunes_link")
    @DataField(pos = 9, length=30, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
    public String itunesLink;
}
```

**ZvkkRequestFixedLenght.java**

```java
@CsvRecord(separator=",")
@FixedLengthRecord
public class ZvkkRequestFixedLenght {
    
    @DataField(pos = 1, length = 5, align = "L", paddingChar = ' ')
    public String blockType;

    @DataField(pos = 2, length = 8, align = "R", paddingChar = '0')
    public int blockTypeLength;
    
    @DataField(pos = 3, length = 15, align = "L", paddingChar = ' ')
    public String blockId;
    
    @DataField(pos = 4, length = 3, align = "R", paddingChar = '0')
    public int totalNoOfTX;
    
    @DataField(pos = 5, length = 5, align = "L", paddingChar = ' ')
    public String msgblockType;
    
    @DataField(pos = 6, length = 8, align = "R", paddingChar = '0')
    public int messageLength;

    @DataField(pos = 7, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
    public String title;
    
    @DataField(pos = 8, length=5, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
    public String artist;

    @DataField(pos = 9, length=30, align = "R", paddingChar=' ')
    public String itunesLink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pasi 
when i am trying to marshal or unmarshal getting -- org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.db.gtbb.adapter.zvkk.model.BillingBookingRequest to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value BillingBookingRequest(blockType=BL-H , blockTypeLength=31, blockId=S62951156229900, totalNoOfTX=1, msgblockType=TX-S , messageLength=728, noa=[DAO(title=Behin, artist=LIMP , itunes_link=http:behind)])

I dont understand if i am missing any dependency ?

Comment: Dependencies for this are `camel-core`, `camel-jackson` and `camel-bindy`

Comment: Hi @Pasi 
Yes i have all of them but still getting this NoTypeConversionAvailableException while unmarshalling -- could you please suggest how to get rid of this ?

Comment: even added annotation  @JsonProperty still getting the noTypeConversionAvailable Excption

Comment: Forgot `@FixedLengthRecord` from above the `ZvkkRequestFixedLenght` class.

Comment: Getting result as 
[BL-H 00000031S62951156229900001TX-S 00000728BehinLIMP                    http:behind
BL-H 00000031S62951156229900001TX-S 00000728AloneALYSS          http:clk.doubler.com]

But i need the final result as [BL-H 00000031S62951156229900001TX-S 00000728BehinLIMP                    http:behindAloneALYSS          http:clk.doubler.com] Dont think it will work this way with @FixedLengthRecord - please do let me know if there is any alternate way to do so

Comment: Well you could possibly marshal ZvkkRequest and DAOFix separately and use string concatenation to combine them, you could also check if [beanio](http://beanio.org/) supports this (haven't used that one yet and seems more involved with its xml configurations) or you could create your own DataFormat that implements the camels DataFormat interface and effectively implement the unmarshal/marshal by yourself.

Comment: Sure @Pasi will try. Yes i have tried implementing this with beanio but the outcome is not what is expected so this is the only possible solution for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help for achieve this.
It worked with marshalling the request parts separately and concatenation later.

Comment: No problem, added the suggestion for string concatenation to my answer so you can mark it accepted and maybe even up vote it.